# Can a pullrequest on bitbucket be locked for further commits?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

Background: A pull request on bitbucket is created for a certain branch in a git repository. Then reviewers are invited to review the code and to approve it.

If then another commit is pushed to that branch while the pull request is reviewed, the reviewers might see different versions of the branch or a reviewer might review the code before it was changed. The approval is also not retracted if a new commit is pushed.

1. Can I lock a pull request to one commit?
2. Can the situation that the code is updated without being noticed by reviewers avoided?

Related:

3. When being created, the commit messages of the branch are included in the pull request. Is there a way to update that section of the pull request if another commit was pushed to the branch?

If yes on any of the questions, please elaborate on how.

Comment: You could create a server-side git hook to reject commits.

Comment: @agilob could you elaborate on how that would work? In the git hook, would I use the bitbucket api to check whether a branch has a current pull request or would I have to install the git hook manually for each pull request?

Answer (score 0):

At least for item 2 it seems there is some kind of support (now).

If one uses [Merge checks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/merge-checks-856691474.html) which is a "Premium" feature, then you can reset approvals once the source branch is altered.

From the linked page:

> Setting: Reset approvals when the source branch of a pull request is modified
>
> Result: If there are any changes to the source branch of the pull request, the approvals will be reset, and the approvers will have to review and approve the pull request again. in order to merge if you've selected a specific number of approvals.